# Jabber/XMPP client with message carbon XEP-0280 support

Tags: software-recommendation, xmpp, jabber

Is there Jabber/XMPP client for Ubuntu that supports 
the message carbon extension ([XEP-0280](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Gajim](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gajim/) supports XEP-0280 ([source](https://trac.gajim.org/wiki/GajimXEPSupport)).
- [Pidgin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pidigin/) doesn't support it ([source](https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/15508)).

Last update: 28/07/2016.

Comment: Many thanks. If someone wants to use it, do not forget to enable it as the default is disabled in Gajim. You need to go : Settings -> advanced tab -> Extended configuration editor : Open -> search for: message_carbon -> double click to change to activate.

Comment: @readyblue: Good point! Do you mind [edit]ing my answer to add that info?

Comment: Pidgin seems to be able to handle carbons with this :

https://github.com/gkdr/carbons